# Can I make python read my file as UTF-16 LE BOM while using regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, utf-8, utf-16

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will take a text file of chapter markers exported from Premiere Pro, and convert it to a format readable by ffmpeg.

Problem is, they come out as a file that Notepad++ reports as UTF-16 LE BOM.  My code will work fine if I change this to UTF-8 and then save it.  But, I'm wondering if there's an easier way to just modify my code instead of converting each .txt file.

This is a test code to just convert the timestamp from hh:mm:ss:ff to milliseconds and print that. Again, it works with UTF-8 files:

```
import math
import re

with open('chapters.txt', 'r') as f:
   next(f)
   for line in f:
      x = re.match(r".*?\t\t\t(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})", line)
      hrs = int(x.group(1))
      mins = int(x.group(2))
      secs = int(x.group(3))
      frms = int(x.group(4))

      minutes = (hrs * 60) + mins
      seconds = secs + (minutes * 60)
      milliseconds = (seconds * 1000)
      frames = math.ceil(frms * 41.7)
      timestamp = (milliseconds + frames)
      print(timestamp)
```

Here's what the files from Premiere Pro look like:

```
    Asset Name              In Point            Description 
    video           00:03:45:10                         
    video           00:12:26:19                         
    video           00:22:30:07                         
    video           00:34:42:22
```

Disclaimer: I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Why don't you set the encoding when you open the file? `with open('chapters.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-16') as f:` should work.

Comment: This is the answer!   Sometimes, the simplest solution is the correct one.  Not sure how to mark this comment as the verified answer, but thank you.